# How to get pointer on a struct member inside a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

My struct are like this :

```
typedef struct Bounds Bounds;
struct Bounds
{
    int type;
    double lb;
    double ub;
};

typedef struct HelperGlpk HelperGlpk;
struct HelperGlpk
{
    double *matrix_coefs;
    double *obj_coefs;
    Bounds *row_bounds;
    Bounds *col_bounds;
    int *column_of_coef;
    int *row_of_coef;
    int cpt_coef;
    int cpt_contrainte;
};
```

I initiliaze them that way (on my main) :

```
HelperGlpk helper_glpk;

    helper_glpk.matrix_coefs = malloc((nbr_coefs + 1) * sizeof(double));
    helper_glpk.matrix_coefs[0] = 0;

    helper_glpk.obj_coefs = malloc((nbr_colums + 1) * sizeof(double));
    helper_glpk.obj_coefs[0] = 0;

    helper_glpk.column_of_coef = malloc((nbr_colums + 1) * sizeof(int));
    helper_glpk.column_of_coef[0] = 0;

    helper_glpk.row_of_coef = malloc((nbr_rows + 1) * sizeof(int)); 
    helper_glpk.row_of_coef[0] = 0;

    helper_glpk.col_bounds = malloc((nbr_colums + 1) * sizeof(Bounds));
    helper_glpk.row_bounds = malloc((nbr_rows + 1) * sizeof(Bounds));

    helper_glpk.cpt_coef = 1;
    helper_glpk.cpt_contrainte = 1;
```

Then, inside the function genere_contrainte_1() that I call this way : `genere_contrainte_1(i, j, &helper_glpk, baie);`

I want to access to the pointer `helper_glpk->col_bounds[helper_glpk->cpt_coef]->type` but I got this error :

```
error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘Bounds {aka struct Bounds}’)
  helper_glpk->col_bounds[helper_glpk->cpt_coef]->type = GLP_DB;
```

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Edit : I DO want to access the pointer to ->type, because .type doesn't "save" the value for use outside the function genere_contrainte_1()

Comment: helper_glpk is a struct, so you should use the `.` operator rather than the `->` operator

Comment: The question should show the function prototype for the `genere_contrainte_1` function.

Comment: In response to the edit: you need to post a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's not clear what you mean by *".type doesn't save the value for use outside the function"*. It should.

Comment: Thanks you, I tough my problem was here but it was something else.

Answer (score 0):

The `col_bounds` member of the `HelperGlpk` structure is being used as an array. Which is to say that

```
helper_glpk->col_bounds[helper_glpk->cpt_coef]
```

is an instance of the `Bounds` structure, *not* a pointer to a `Bounds` structure.

Hence, the correct syntax uses the dot notation

```
helper_glpk->col_bounds[helper_glpk->cpt_coef].type = GLP_DB;
```

Comment: My problem is that I want to access the pointer to type, because I'm inside a function. (I edited my post)

Answer (score 0):

`helper_glpk->col_bounds` evaluates to a `Bounds*`.

`helper_glpk->col_bounds[helper_glpk->cpt_coef]` evaluates to a `Bounds`.

Hence, you need to use:

```
helper_glpk->col_bounds[helper_glpk->cpt_coef].type = GLP_DB;
                                           // ^^ Use . not ->
```

Comment: My problem is that I want to access the pointer to type, because I'm inside a function.